# How to show overlay screen over tabBar?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In `main.lua` I create tabBar with three buttons and three screens (**screen1, screen2, screen3**)

1. In **screen1** I would like to show modal overlay

   ```
   local options = {
           effect = "fromBottom",
           time = 400,
           isModal = true,
       }

   storyboard.showOverlay( "get", options )
   ```

Everything works, but I would like to show the overlay over tabBar (like modal view in xCode).
How can I do it?

1. In one case I should "goto" **screen3** from **screen1**

   ```
   storyboard.gotoScene( "screen3")
   ```

It's works, but selected tabButton is still **tabButton1** (with **screen1**)

How to select tabButton programmatically?

Here is the code of creating **tabBar** in `main.lua`:

```
-- Create buttons table for the tab bar
local tabButtons = {
    {
        width = 32, height = 32,
        defaultFile = "assets/tabIcon.png", overFile = "assets/tabIcon-down.png",
        label = translations["tab1"][language],
        onPress = function() storyboard.gotoScene( "screen1" ); end,
        selected = true
    },
    {
        width = 32, height = 32,
        defaultFile = "assets/tabIcon.png", overFile = "assets/tabIcon-down.png",
        label = translations["tab2"][language],
        onPress = function() storyboard.gotoScene( "screen2" ); end,
    },
    {
        width = 32, height = 32,
        defaultFile = "assets/tabIcon.png", overFile = "assets/tabIcon-down.png",
        label = translations["tab3"][language],
        onPress = function() storyboard.gotoScene( "screen3" ); end,
    }
}
--Create a tab-bar and place it at the bottom of the screen
local tabBar = widget.newTabBar {
    top = display.contentHeight - 50,
    height = 50,
    width = display.contentWidth,
    --backgroundFile = "assets/tabbar.png",
    tabSelectedFrameWidth = 1,
    tabSelectedFrameHeight = 49,
    buttons = tabButtons 
}
storyboard.gotoScene( "screen1", "crossFade", 200 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can show any image over the tab bar since it's a native object.  The only way I could see it possibly working is by inserting the image and tabBar into a 2 groups.  Then making the one `display.newGroup()` over the other one.  I don't even think that will work though, but give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Corona's case, if you are using widget.newTabBar(), they are Corona display objects. I think the issue you are running into is that storyboard objects live below any objects that are not being managed by storyboard.

Because your tabBar is typically not managed by storyboard it will sit on top of any storyboard scene, including overlays.  To make this work the way you want, you would probably need to create a scene (call it menu.lua or tabbar.lua) that creates the tabBar in it's createScene function and make sure to add the tabBar to the scene's view. Now that scene is being managed by storyboard and your overlay can now cover it.

Comment: Thank you, Rob! But what do you mean by "make sure to add the tabBar to the scene's view"?

Comment: In the createScene() there is a line that looks like:

local group = self.view

This is the scene's "view" or it's group.  Simply do a group:insert(tabBar) after you create the tabBar (assuming you named it tabBar)